# Access DOM of Safari documents from Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, safari, applescript

Is it possible to somehow enumerate opened Safari documents and access their DOM from my own third-party Cocoa application?

I thought about writing a Safari extension that could help me to do such an interaction, but maybe there is an easier way to achieve the same results.

Comment: Yes, maybe javascript ejection. Something like getting WebKit control of any document within Safari. Although, I think allowing this would be the serious security flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps, but you can access a specific element via AppleScript like this:

```
  tell application "Safari"
    set xxx to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('user-details')[0].childNodes[0].href" in document 1
end tell
```

(Gives you the URL to your user profile from this page)

Comment: Thanks. That's much better. So I can not only retrieving DOM elements and other information from documents, but also send some other JavaScript events. This is very helpful, indeed.

Comment: What do you think about implementing this AppleScript code in Objective-C using AppleScript Bridging mechanisms? Is there an example or supplementary documentation?

Comment: I am unsure about the best way of doing that. Can you call osascript from Objective-C ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is interesting for you:
http://phantomjs.org/
The source is also available.